# Why are Facebook Graph API permissions so weird?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-page

I have created a Facebook page. On the page I have created some events and some notes. Everything as public as possible. Now I want to expose the data on my website using the Graph API.

The general data of the page is accessable without any access token, which is nice. 
The event data is accessable using a FB app with app_id and app_secret. 
For the notes you need a "user access token", which isn't an option, because not all of the website visitors have a FB account.

Why must it be so complicated? Does anyone have a solution?

Greetings
Allan

Comment: According to this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note/ as long as the notes are public any user access token should work, but having tested this I can confirm the behaviour you are seeing. Perhaps file a bug at facebook https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Seems like it has already been filed: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/402021703178054 but they are not moving so fast.

Comment: Another thing, when you're writing a note logged in as a page, there's no way of setting the visibility permission. At least I can't find it.